# Is it possible to customize Apple Developer Program Roles?

Tags: ios, roles, membership

We would like to outsource a project for our organization but we don't want to give 'Admin' permissions to consultants and 'Member' permissions aren't sufficient. Is there a way we could customize both the roles or what is our option around presets?

Additional information from Apple - [Managing Your Team in Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the worst thing they could do as admins that you fear? Don't forget there is a level higher than Admin which is the Agent. Once the project is complete if you were worried about them revoking a certificate then as the Agent you can remove or downgrade them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no middle ground. You can either trust them wholeheartedly as Admins, or do all the provisioning process yourself and let them download the files as Members.

Admins cannot touch any of the iTunes Connect stuff, so about the worst they could do is kick people off your developer account or revoke certificates.